# How to get the GCD of command line argument integers entered by the user after './a.out' in any order?

Tags: c, arrays, unix, greatest-common-divisor

This program returns the GCD of the command line
args inputed by the user ONLY from least to greastest.
For example:

User input:  './a.out 5 10 15 20 25 '

This program returns: "The GCD of the command line args is 5"

However, the problem I am running into is if the user types for example:

User input: './a.out 15 10 5 25 20'

This program returns: 15

Can someone tell me how to fix this issue?

This is what I am aiming for:

If user input: './a.out 15 10 5 25 20'

This program should return: 5

```
//Header Files
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

//Main Method
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

//Declared variables here and print statements
 int i,x,y,min;
 printf("Number of command line args is %d\n", argc);
 printf("The GCD is:\t");

 //This is the main while loop
 while( x !=0 && y !=0 && y != x){

 if(x<y){
  y=y-x;
 }//End first IF statement
 if(y<x){
  x-x-y;
 }//End second IF statement
 }//End while loop

 //This function returns the converted integral number as an int value
  x=atoi(argv[i]);
  for(i=2;i<argc;i++){
  y=atoi(argv[i]);
   }

   //The following code gets the GCD and prints from the command line
   min = (x>y)?x:y;
  for(i=min;i>=1;--i){
  if(x%i==0 && y%i==0){
  for(i=1;i<argc;i++){
   printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    break;}//End for loop
    }//End IF statement
   }//End For loop
  }//End of MAIN
```

Comment: Is this the actual program or have you jumbled it up? Have you left out parts of it?

Comment: This is the actual program. Do you understand how you must type the numbers after ./a.out?

Comment: `i` (and some other variables) are not initialized. The first while loop seems useless anyway. But please indent your code properly.

Comment: Sure thing, thanks for responding!

Comment: It does not matter how you enter the numbers as arguments, this code will not give you the desired output. There are flaws in your code, I've posted a cleaned up one below in the answer.

Comment: this line: 'while( x !=0 && y !=0 && y != x){' is using the variable 'x' and 'y' however, especially on the first iteration, these variables are not initialized

Comment: indenting the code after each opening brace and unindenting at each closing brace would make the code much clearer/understandable and much easier for us to reverse engineer it to try and determine what went wrong.  Suggest using an indent of 4 spaces (and NEVER use tabs for formatting code

Comment: the code is retrieving parameters from the command line without FIRST assuring that such parameters exist.  Generally, it is best to, first thing in main, check the number of parameters with argc,  printing a error message or usage message if that argc number is not suitable then exit.

Comment: the code block, beginning with: 'while( x !=0 && y !=0 && y != x){' is doing nothing but tweaking some trash that happened to be on the stack where the variables 'x' and 'y' are located.  I.E. it does absolutely nothing for the program

Comment: this code block: for(i=2;i<argc;i++){   y=atoi(argv[i]);'' puts the first parameter (assuming it exists) into 'x' and puts the last parameter into 'y'  all other numbers are lost

Comment: what is expected to happen if the first or last parameter is 0?  What is expected to happen of there are no parameters?  what is expected to happen if there is only 1 parameter?

Comment: what is expected to happen of either the first parameter of the last parameter are not multiples of each other?

Comment: the inner most for loop, near the end of the code, will never execute more than one loop due to the 'break;' statement.  Is that what you really want to happen?

Comment: the inner most loop contains a printf() statement that uses argv[i], however 'i' could be any value in the range of the input parameter values (not the number of input parameters)  so argv[i] can be past the end of the argv[] array.  resulting in undefined behaviour and can/will lead to a seg fault event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've cleaned it up, this should work for you:

Initialize every variable before you consider it up for calculation in your code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

//Main Method
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

//Declared variables here and print statements
 int i,x,y,gcd;
 printf("Number of command line args is %d\n", argc);
 printf("The GCD is:\t");
 x=atoi(argv[1]);
 for(i=2;i<argc;i++){
    y=atoi(argv[i]);
    while( x !=0 && y !=0 && y != x){
        if(x<y){
            y=y-x;
        }else if(y<x){
            x=x-y;
        }
    }
    gcd=x;
 }
 printf("%d",gcd);
}//End of MAIN
```

Comment: This program you've cleaned up doesn't work because it only returns 0 now.

Comment: What are your input parameters?

Comment: ./a.out 5 10 15

Program returns:    0

Comment: My bad, i missed that the 1st parameter is the file name, i have corrected it, please try now.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to do with recursion.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int GCD(int numbers[], int count)
{
    if (count==1)
        return numbers[0];
    int i, j, min, x, y;
    x = numbers[0];
    y = numbers[1];
    min = (x>y)?x:y;
    for(i=min;i>=1;--i){
        if(x%i==0 && y%i==0){
            int newNumbers[count-1];
            newNumbers[0]=i;
            for (j=1; j<count-1; j++) {
                newNumbers[j] = numbers[j+1];
            }
            return GCD(newNumbers, count-1);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    //Declared variables here and print statements
    int i;
    printf("Number of command line args is %d\n", argc);
    printf("The GCD is:\t");

    int numbers[argc];

    for(i=1;i<argc;i++){
        numbers[i]=atoi(argv[i]);
    }

    int result = GCD(numbers, argc);
    printf("%d\n", result);

}
```